# Setup RPL in non storing mode

Tags: contiki

I am new to Contiki and using Contiki 3.0. Can anyone please help me on following points:

1. How to set RPL into non storing mode from storing mode which is the default one? I'm trying with changing DAG mode in rpl-private.h but it seems it's not the correct way.
2. Cooja Collect View  works only with example simulation given in examples/rpl-collect and not in my custom simulation project. Is any setting required for it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
#undef RPL_CONF_MOP
#define RPL_CONF_MOP RPL_MOP_NON_STORING /* Mode of operation*/
#undef UIP_CONF_MAX_ROUTES
#define UIP_CONF_MAX_ROUTES 0 /* Optional, but helps to save memory - no need for routes in the non-storing mode */
```

Leave comment if it does not work for any reasons.

Comment: This is setting RPL into Non storing. However, I'm not sure why rpl_add_route() is being called for all non root nodes for each DAO. i.e. In non storing mode only root node should have routing details ?

Comment: Apologies, I was checking RPL code given in instant contiki. I guess it supports storing mode only.